# Adobe could not perform recognition: This page is larger than the maximum page size of 45 inches by 45 inches

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, ocr

I tried to run the text recognition tool in a PDF, and obtain the following error message:

> Adobe could not perform recognition (OCR) on this page because: 
> This page is larger than the maximum page size of 45 inches by 45 inches.

[image]

Is there any way around so that I can run the OCR on the PDF?

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro XI with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 3):

An absolutely legitimate question.

The primary workaround is opening the scanned document in an image editor (Photoshop, theGIMP, etc.) and increase the resolution. This will NOT lead to a scaling, because the size of the picture (in pixel) will remain the same.

With the higher resolution, the picture will become smaller in inch, cm, etc., and Acrobat can deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Max's suggestion, I'm providing a Mac solution here:

1. export the PDF into an image (or many images)
2. open an image with Mac Preview
3. Tools -> Adjust Size
4. uncheck resample image
5. type a desired resolution, OK
6. And then convert to PDF, perform OCR